# Unity switching to third camera turns game objects invisible

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm having a problem with some of my game objects (walls of rooms) turning invisible when I switch from my first person camera to my third person camera. The layer that the walls is on is NOT selected by either camera's culling mask. The camera settings should all match because I created the third person camera by duplicating the first person camera and then moving it to a new position. The game starts with the first person camera active and the third person camera inactive.

Does anyone have suggestions for what might be causing this problem?

Comment: If the layer is **not** selected in the cameras culling mask, then it **should not** be visible, but you probably mean the other way round? Anyway, only thing I can think of is the clipping planes, because the third person camera might be further back? What happens if you duplicate the FPS camera again and look at the preview? Are the walls still invisible?

Comment: Please show the problem with the two comparison images.